# Image not showing when using BackboneJS app within Heroku

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, heroku, express

I have an app built on `BackboneJS`.  I have an image in the navbar that shows find in my local environment, but I get a `404` from the image when I push the code to Heroku.  I have checked and the image is for sure on `Github`.  Here is my code that refers to the image:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" >
        <img src="../app/img/isxLogo.png" width="56" class="navbar-brand">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I am using a relative path.  The image name is also spelled right with no capitalization differences.  What else am I missing?

Comment: What framework are you using server-side? (e.g. Rails)  Which Heroku stack are you on? (e.g. Cedar, Bamboo)

Comment: I am using `expressjs` for my server.

Comment: Have you tried using a non-relative path for the `src` attribute? Something like `src="/whatever/the/top/is/app/img/isxLogo.png"` for a suitable `whatever/the/top/is`. Relative paths are more trouble that they're worth.

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant, but what would the root be to the app?  Could you send me to a link that could give me an example?

Comment: Have you set your static directory in express? http://expressjs.com/api.html#directory this will tell you what to base the path for your image off of. For instance, if you set it to 'app/assets' and put your img folder inside app/assests, you could reference any image by 'img/imagename.ext'.